# Nvidia Tesla XEN PCIpassthrough

Tags: xen, passthrough, cuda

has anyone managed/tried to pci passthrough an nvidia tesla card to a xen domU?

Answer (score 1):

XenServer Boston, which is still in beta, is supposed to support this.  Sorry I haven't tried this myself!  Good luck!